# 2D grid which is topologically equivalent to a sphere?

Tags: general-topology

I admit that my knowledge of topology is limited to the idea that a mug and doughnut are homomorphic since you can morph one into the other with a continuous deformation. I am a game dev working on a game which is played on a 2D grid. We were talking about how to wrap the edges of the map such that the grid is topologically equivalent to a sphere. The first idea we had was to wrap the horizontal edges so you warp from the left edge to the right edge, and you warp from the top most to the bottom edge. However, after some hand waving and a few badly folded pieces of paper, we determined that this was actually equivalent to a torus. The next idea was just to wrap the horizontal edges, but this is also a problem since there are two points on that shape which cannot be traversed at the north and south poles. The third idea was to wrap the horizontal edges as before, but have the edges at the top and bottom wrap so that if you went off the top edge, you would be warped horizontally half the grid width (modulo the grid width or something), but still be on the top edge. Same thing for the bottom edge. Now the bottom and top edges of the grid do not touch. You could travel in one direction vertically and end up exactly where you started. My intuition gathered from folding a piece of paper in half and looking at where the edges touch says this is correct, but I was wondering if there was a more rigorous way to think about this problem.

Comment: One way to do it is like in the picture at the bottom of this page: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part2.htm

Comment: So if I am understanding that picture right, a correct way to get a sphere from my 2d grid is to wrap the top edge to the left edge, and the bottom edge to the right?

Comment: I think I am starting to see why our third idea is wrong. Our intuition was that we were somehow collapsing the top edge into a single point (the north pole) and likewise for the bottom. However, if that were true, then all of the top edge should be touching the rest of the top edge, which is not the case. Even if I cross the top edge, the point which is one quarter of the grid width away on the top edge is still just as far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your criteria, this can either be done or not done. If the edges of the grid are labelled clockwise with $a,b,c,d$ then by gluing $a$ to $b$ and $c$ to $d$, you are left with something which is topologically a sphere, but its metric properties are not those of the usual sphere (constant positive curvature). It has points which act like 'cone points' where you only have to turn $90$ degrees in order to end up facing the same way you were facing before.

If you want the metric properties of the sphere to be preserved, then this is impossible due to the grid being flat (it's a portion of Euclidean space) which has $0$ curvature, and the sphere having strictly positive (so non-zero) curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is wrong. Putting in a half-cycle shift doesn't change the result topologically -- you still get something that's a torus. Imagine a dog's large soft rubber chew-toy in the shape of a torus. Let it lie on a table, and slice it vertically, but only through one side, so you get something that's like a letter "C" with the top and bottom ends right next to each other. Now grab the two sides of the cut, one in each hand, and twist them while keeping their faces adjacent, adn then glue them back together with some hot-glue. Whether you twisted 5 degees, 20 degrees, or 180 degrees, you've still got a torus. That's what you've done in your description above: you've applied a twist along the glue-line.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I understand that if I wrapped the top edge so that it touches the bottom edge, then shifting the warp still results in a torus, but I'm still unclear why the wrap we proposed at the end (in which the bottom and top do not touch) is still a torus. Sorry if I'm being dense...

Comment: You're completely right -- I mis-read your description. What you describe -- taking the top of an upright cylinder (described by points $(\theta, h)$, where $\theta$ is in the circle, and $-1 le h \le 1$ is "height", and gluing $(\theta, 1)$ to $(\theta + \pi, 1)$ doesn't do what you want, but gluing $(\theta, 1)$ to $(2\pi - \theta, 1)$ (mod 2 $\pi$) actually does work. The "shift a half-turn" thing you propose, done to both the top and bottom circle of a cylinder, results in "the connected sum of two projective planes", which is also called a "Klein bottle", which wasn't what you wanted.